# Python. How auth on the site?

Tags: python, python-requests, http-status-code-403

I have task. Me need download image from site. Site using auth when trying downloading. Part of my code:

```
import requests
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        s = requests.session()
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36',
            'ForceUseSession': 'true'
        }
        data={'UserName': 'Login', 'UserPassword': 'Password'}
        p = s.post('https://mysite.ru/Login', headers=headers, data=data)
        s.cookies
        print(p.text)
    except Exception as e:
            print(f"\n\n\n\n{e}\n\n\n")
time.sleep(50)
```

After run script i get this answer:

```
    requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - "POST /Login HTTP/1.1" 400 3069
ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Request Error</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <p class="heading1">Request Error</p>
      <p>The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'There was an error checking start element of object of type Core.ServiceModelContract.AuthToken. Encountered unexpected character 'U'.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is: </p>
      <p>   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.IsStartObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterMessageFormatter.ReadObject(Message message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterDataContractMessageFormatter.ReadObject(Message message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And how download image using requests?

---

Authorization was performed using this method, but you can't download the image. Writes error 403.
I was told to use cookies, but I didn't find any information about them for fix this problem

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager(ca_certs=certifi.where())

payload = {'UserName': 'Login', 'UserPassword': 'Password'}
encoded_data = json.dumps(payload).encode('utf-8')

resp = http.request(
     'POST',
     'https://mysite.ru/Login',
     body=encoded_data,
     headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

data = json.loads(resp.data.decode('utf-8'))
urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://mysite.ru/img/1", f"tmp/test.jpg")
```

---

Fix:
in line
p = s.post('https://mysite.ru/Login', headers=headers, data=data)

edit data:
p = s.post('https://mysite.ru/Login', headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))

Comment: Your code has invalid syntax - its not a [mcve].

Comment: @SuperStormer added code in start topic

Comment: What site......?

Comment: @West intranet portal(

Comment: Use `requests.Session()`